# XmlSerializer with custom transform using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xmlserializer

Is there a way to deserialize a XML stream using XmlSerializer by applying a custom transform defined in a XSLT?

Comment: What language/libraries are you working with?

Comment: Thanks for responsing, C# .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a single API call that would allow that but you could certainly implement that with a few lines along the following approach:

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load("sheet.xsl");

XmlDocument tempResult = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlWriter xw = tempResult.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
  proc.Transform("input.xml", null, xw);
  xw.Close();
}

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
Foo foo = (Foo)ser.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(tempResult));
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've something similar now, the problem is the transform files are fairly large around 500K-1M. When multiple XML documents are processed concurrently, say around 10 XMLs, the memory spikes to 1.5G+ and processor on a dual core runs between 98-99% usage. With 1 document, the processor usage is stil 98-99% but the memory usage is around 300M

Machine specs:
2x2dual core Intel Xeon 1.6GHz
4G 
Windows 2008 x64

Comment: Okay, leanred something new. Used the same code as above and used another overload .Load(Type) instead of .Load(String). This shot down the resource utlization to 1/10th ... thanks for you assistance Martin.